# JTable rows are rendering way to small

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable

For some reason, all of my JTable rows are extra small?

This code:

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(sheetRowHeight, sheetMaxCellLength);

        int rCount=0;
        int cCount=0;
        for (ArrayList a:tableData)
        {
            for(Object o:a)
            {
                String s =(String)o;
                tableModel.setValueAt(s, rCount, cCount);
                cCount++;
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            cCount=0;
            rCount++;
        }

        //all data should now be in tablemodel
        System.out.println("setting model");
        tableView.setModel(tableModel);
```

Gives me this:
[image]
Any ideas on what the hell is happening here? Thanks.

EDIT: The issue was that netbeans was autogenerating some code that called tableView.setRowHeight() and that was messing things up.

Comment: A TableModel has nothing to do with the rendering of the table, so the code you posted is useless (unless of course your data is some wierd HTML). Either way, post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem so we can get a better idea what you are doing.

Comment: Ok, so which part of my code would be helpful for diagnosing the problem?

Comment: 'which part of my code would be helpful'  You have not read the SSCCE link, have you?